# How to return T value through a compile-time "if"?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to do something like:

```
template<typename T>
T func()
{
    if(T is int)
        return 1;
    if(T is std::string)
       return std::string("hello");//this line will not be able to compile if T is int
}
```

Could any one tell me how to solve this? THX a lot.

Answer (score 4):

using template specialization for example...

```
template<typename T>
T func();

template<>
int func() { return 1; }

template<>
std::string func() { return "hello"; }
```

or with `enable_if`.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int>::type func()
{
   return 1;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, std::string>::type 
func()
{
   return "hello";
}
```

If you want not only int/string, but types from which we can construct int/string you can use `decltype`.

```
template<typename T>
auto func() -> decltype(int{std::declval<T>()})
{
   return 1;
}

template<typename T>
auto func() -> decltype(std::string{std::declval<T>()})
{
   return "hello";
}
```

clang compiles this fine, but gcc 4.8 cannot and brokes with internal compiler error.

Comment: Would have been nice if there was a way to do it with a "template lambda". Can't template it afaik though.

Comment: So  it can't be more simple than just to implement the  `int funcInt()` and the `string funcString()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template<class T>
struct CommonTraits {
    static T Return(){
    }
};
template<>
struct CommonTraits<int>{
    static int Return(){
        return 1;
    }
};
template<>
struct CommonTraits<std::string>{
    static std::string Return(){
        return std::string("hello");
    }
};

int main ()
{
    std::cout<<CommonTraits<std::string>::Return()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<CommonTraits<int>::Return()<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with.. It uses C++14.

```
template<typename T, typename Tupple, size_t... index>
constexpr T construct_type(Tupple&& params, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    return T(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tupple>(params))...);
}

template<typename T, typename Tupple>
constexpr T construct(Tupple&& params)
{
    return construct_type<T, Tupple>(std::forward<Tupple>(params), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tupple>::type>::value>{});
}

template<bool cond, typename T, typename F>
struct cond_if
{
    template<typename FirstArgs, typename SecondArgs>
    constexpr T value(FirstArgs&& first, SecondArgs&& second) {return construct<T>(first);}
};

template<typename T, typename F>
struct cond_if<false, T, F>
{
    template<typename FirstArgs, typename SecondArgs>
    constexpr F value(FirstArgs&& first, SecondArgs&& second) {return construct<F>(second);}
};



template<typename T>
constexpr auto func()
{
    return cond_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int, std::string>().value(std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple("Hello"));
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto func2()
{
    return cond_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int, const char*>().value(std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple("Hello"));
}


int main()
{
    static_assert(func<int>() == 1, "NOT COMPILE TIME -- 1");
    static_assert(func2<char>() == "Hello", "NOT COMPILE TIME -- 2");
    static_assert(func<char>() == "Hello", "NOT COMPILE TIME -- 3");
}
```

Output:

```
NOT COMPILE TIME -- 3 - Non-constant condition for static assertion.
```

The third instance is not compile time due to the `std::string` being used.